# Como gerar APK de um projeto ExpoKit?

Tags: react-native, expo

Estava com um projeto Expo, mas devido a necessidade de aplicar formas de pagamento precisei ejetar o projeto para ter as pastas /android e /ios para editar elas diretamente. Decidi usar react-native-iap, então ejetei para um projeto ExpoKit, já que é recomendado pela documentação Expo já que continua a usar propriedades do Expo, ao contrário duma ejeção completa. 
Então... fiz as edições certinho, mas como faço pra gerar o apk do aplicativo? Já que 'expo build:android' não funciona nesse tipo de projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Coloque a Keystore em android/app

2 - Altere um dos arquivos : ~/.gradle/gradle.properties ou android/gradle.properties alterando para as configs da sua keystore:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=minha_key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=minha_key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

3 - Edite android/app/build.gradle e adicione as variaveis acima:

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

4 - Para gerar :

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

A APK vai estar em :  android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

Qualquer dúvida, veja aqui :
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#docsNav

Comment: Obrigado mano, eu já consegui gerar. Meu problema agora é pra executar no meu celular ou emulador, criei uma pergunta e se puder me ajudar eu agradeço bastante, estou preso nisso e não sei como resolver: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347821/como-executar-um-projeto-expokit-num-celular-emulador-para-desenvolvimento E devido a demora, criei um no site em inglês, com mais detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695334/how-to-fix-error-permission-denial-when-executing-command-react-native-run-an Me ajuda, por favor

Comment: boa! mas se a resposta foi útil, é sempre bom agradecer...

Comment: Estranho, achei que já tinha dado upvote na resposta

Comment: Boa!  mandei um link para a sua outra dúvida, como você fez um eject, pode ser que ele te ajude

Comment: Antes de gerar o .apk de produção utilize o comando `expo publish` para deixar seus JS num CDN da própria Expo.

Comment: @Luídne eu já dei o expo publish, mas quando eu gero o apk, instalo no meu celular e tento executar ele fala que o app não pode ser carregado. Alguma solução?

Comment: Verifica os URLs no projeto android (MainActivity.java) se é o mesmo que aparece no final quando executa `expo publish`