# Como executar um projeto Expokit num celular/emulador para desenvolvimento?

Tags: android, windows, react-native, expo

Eu tinha um projeto feito em Expo, mas ejetei ele usando Expokit, que cria as pastas /android e /ios, eu consigo gerar a apk entretanto não consigo emular no meu celular para desenvolvimento. O comando que uso para construir a apk é `gradlew assembleRelease`, tentei usar `react-native run-android` mas deu erro. Alguma sugestão de como executar um projeto no meu celular/emulador para desenvolvimento? Segue a imagem com o erro após `react-native run-android`:

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Recomendo usar o Android Studio para executar o no emulador, uma vez executado não precisará mais do Android Studio aberto (só precisará de novo quando mudar o URL do servidor Expo)